UAC prompt for file signed by smctl always displays a randomly-generated file name
When I use a digicert smctl sign command (with Key Locker) to sign an MSI binary it puts a randomly generated ".msi" name in the description when the UAC prompt pops up. This is less than reassuring for people installing the app I am building. Under the hood it looks like they are using signtool command without a "/d" parameter.
Previously when I used signtool this was easily fixable by adding the "/d" parameter - how can I fix the file description when using smctl? I cannot figure out any way to customize the signtool call that smctl is making.

Looking at the smctl manual, there is a --file-name that seems to be equivalent to the signtool /d parameter.
smctl uses Jsign under the hood for signing MSI files, you can also use it directly and specify the --name parameter (disclaimer: I'm the author of Jsign). The syntax looks like this:
jsign --storetype DIGICERTONE \
      --storepass "<api-key>|/path/to/Certificate_pkcs12.p12|<password>" \
      --alias test
      --name AppName
      application.exe


I don't think this works. If you run the sign command with --verbose option it does not look like smctl is adding the "/d" parameter (or any other parameter) to the signtool command.

@Patrick Did you try directly with jsign instead?

I am just using SignTool directly now, I reached out to their support and it looks like they do not support this with smctl at all.
